# Mixing 64/32-bit userspace in arm64 linux ( using CONFIG_COMPAT )

Tags: c, linux, arm64

I am looking into 32-bit userspace support in ARM64 linux kernels, and it looks like enabling CONFIG_COMPAT would allow me to do that.

Can anyone chime in on whether enabling CONFIG_COMPAT would DISABLE the running of 64-bit apps? I ask this for the following reasons:

1. The documentation doesn't state that both 64/32 bit apps can be run with the same kernel
2. I took a look at fs/compat_binfmt_elf.c

   ```
   #ifdef   COMPAT_SET_PERSONALITY
   #undef   SET_PERSONALITY
   #define  SET_PERSONALITY      COMPAT_SET_PERSONALITY
   #endif
   ```

   This seems to force the thread personality to

   ```
   set_thread_flag(TIF_32BIT)
   ```
3. When load_elf_binary() in kernel/linux-3.14/fs/binfmt_elf.c is called, there is a call to SET_PERSONALITY(loc->elf_ex);
4. So ineffect, when CONFIG_COMPAT is enabled, all userspace apps are force marked as 32-BIT?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Note that compat_binfmt_elf.c includes binfmt_elf.c at the very end - it recompiles the binfmt_elf.c code into an additional object file, after having juggled defines and set up some renaming for the globally visible symbols.

So it forces all applications running under the compat layer to run as 32-bit, and all applications running natively to run as 64-bit.